# What is the difference between these two sections of code

Tags: python, struct

Hi guys I have two sections of code, what is confusing me, is although they should be equivalent I am not receiving the same results when running both of these code, what is the difference between them ?

Here is the first and working section :

```
packet = struct.pack(">BHHLH", relayCmd, 0, streamId, 0, len(payload)) + payload
```

and second non working section :

```
#     packet = struct.pack(">B", relayCmd)
#     packet += struct.pack("H", 0)
#     packet += struct.pack("H", streamId)
#     packet += struct.pack("L", 0)
#     packet += struct.pack("H", len(payload))
#     packet += payload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version you specify the format to Big Endian by ">" and then all of the formats parameters are encoded this way. In the second example you specify the Big Endian only in the first line and then all of the other parameters are encoded using *native* encoding of the system ("@" is used as default).

Answer (score 1):

From the `struct` documentation:

> **Note**: By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad bytes, use `standard` size and alignment instead of `native` size and alignment: see Byte Order, Size, and Alignment for details.

You used the default `@` alignment (using `native` alignment) when you didn't specify the alignment for the 4 additional lines. You only used `>` standard alignment for the first `relayCmd` codepoint.

As a result, the sizes produced are different:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize('>BHHLH')
11
>>> struct.calcsize('>B')
1
>>> struct.calcsize('H')
2
>>> struct.calcsize('L')
8
>>> 1 + 3 * 2 + 8
15
```

The difference is in the padded `L`; if you use the `>` big endian marker for *all* `pack()` calls it only takes *four* bytes:

```
>>> struct.calcsize('>L')
4
```

So this works:

```
packet = struct.pack(">B", relayCmd)
packet += struct.pack(">H", 0)
packet += struct.pack(">H", streamId)
packet += struct.pack(">L", 0)
packet += struct.pack(">H", len(payload))
packet += payload
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to prepend `>` to each letter so everything is big-endian.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import struct

relayCmd = 170
streamId = 10000
payload = "A"

packet = struct.pack(">BHHLH", relayCmd, 0, streamId, 0, len(payload)) + payload

print(''.join("{:02x} ".format(ord(i)) for i in packet))

packet = struct.pack(">B", relayCmd)
packet += struct.pack(">H", 0)
packet += struct.pack(">H", streamId)
packet += struct.pack(">L", 0)
packet += struct.pack(">H", len(payload))
packet += payload

print(''.join("{:02x} ".format(ord(i)) for i in packet))
```